# How to search a xml file from android mobile sd card

Tags: android, file, xml-parsing, sd-card

I am having a XML file in sd card. I want to search the entire sd card and find that file.
After that i have to parse that file.

I have done a like below.But could not get the file..

```
static final String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getPath() + "/download/";
static final String FILE_NAME = "aura_key.xml";

static File isKeyExist() {
     File file = new File(PATH+FILE_NAME);

     if(file.exists())
     {
         return file;
     }else

    return file;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your complete path in Log to confirm the correct path. BTW what the problem did you face any error?

Comment: i am getting null.. no log cat errors

Comment: Getting null and no log cat errors? wow

Comment: @Pratik If you have a piece of code for this, help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search in the whole external storage, you need to look in all directories and subdirectories etc...

here's a sample solution, just call the first method with your filename (including file extension in your case :

```
searchForFileInExternalStorage("aura_key.xml");
```

and here are the methods :

```
public File searchForFileInExternalStorage(String filename) {
    File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    return searchForFileInFolder(filename, storage);
}

public File searchForFileInFolder(String filename, File folder) {
    File[] children = folder.listFiles();
    File result;

    for (File child : children) {
        if (child.isDirectory()) {
            result = searchForFileInFolder(filename, child);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        } else {
            // replace equals by equalsIgnoreCase if you want to ignore the
            // case of the file name
            if (child.getName().equals(filename)) {
                return child;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean checkdirAvail(String yourpath) {
    boolean ret = true;

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "Problem creating Image folder");
            ret = false;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```